# C - cannot initialize struct "error: initializer element is not constant"

Tags: c, struct

My issue is fairly straightforward. I am trying to initialize the struct in my main function but I get the following error:

```
$ gcc main2.c -o main2
main2.c: In function ‘main’:
main2.c:39:28: error: initializer element is not constant
             .smth.array = (mylib_B_t)
                            ^
main2.c:39:28: note: (near initialization for ‘C.smth.array’)
```

I tried multiple different ways, yet nothing seems to work.
Could someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?
Below is the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mylib_A_t mylib_A_t;
typedef struct mylib_B_t mylib_B_t;
typedef struct mylib_C_t mylib_C_t;

typedef enum
{
    TYPE_A = 0,
    TYPE_B  = -1
} lib_type_t;

struct mylib_A_t
{
    lib_type_t type;
    int d;
};

struct mylib_B_t
{
     int c;
     const mylib_A_t *size;
 };

struct mylib_C_t
{
    union
    {
        int b;
        mylib_B_t array;
     } smth;
};

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    static const mylib_C_t C=
    {

        .smth.array = (mylib_B_t)
        {
            .c = 66,
            .size = &(mylib_A_t)
                   {
                       .type = TYPE_A,
                       .d = 0
                   }
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `field` in the error message? It is not in the source code.

Comment: I assume you confused `field` with `smth.array` in your MCVE.The address of a memory object is not considered a constant expression. For static memory objects you need constant initializers. The problem is this line then: `.size = &(mylib_A_t)`. Make `C` non static or initialize `.size` during runtime. Also `size` is a very strange name for a pointer....

Comment: The code is far from "straightforward" especially when you name a pointer to a struct as `const mylib_A_t *size;`

Answer (score 4):

Initializers for objects with static storage duration must consist of constant expressions.  Your code runs afoul of that in two ways, both related to use of compound literals.

This is a compound literal of type `mylib_A_t`:

> ```
> (mylib_A_t)
> {
>     .type = TYPE_A,
>     .d = 0
> }
> ```

.  It represents an *object* of type `mylib_A_t`, and even though its initial value is defined in terms of constants, it is neither a "constant" nor a "constant expression" as the standard uses that term.

You also seem not to appreciate that although they have similar syntax, initialization expressions, including nested initializers, are *not* assignment statements, and they do not follow the same rules.  In particular, the standard specifies that

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers [as opposed to elsewhere].
>   Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the
>   following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.

([C2011, 6.6/7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p7))

You can write your initialization like so:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // You cannot avoid a declaration of such a static-duration object if
    // you want to use a pointer to such an object in the initializer of C:
    static const mylib_A_t A = {
        .type = TYPE_A,
        .d = 0
    };

    static const mylib_C_t C = {
        // The initializer for .smth.array must be (just) a brace-enclosed
        // initializer list, NOT a compound literal
        .smth.array = {
            .c = 66,
            // &A is an address constant; the pointer expression in your
            // original code is not
            .size = &A
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

There, all the initializers are written in terms of the kinds of constant expressions that are permitted in that context.

Comment: Thx for your answer, a few questions however. 1)By " 'they' have similar syntax.."  are you referring to constant expressions and initialization expressions? 2) I tried reproducing the code above with a constant pointer but still didn't work. An address is a constant value, or am I crazy? Yet neither did the code above work  neither this simplified snippet: https://pastebin.com/8ZqFBQnn
3) why is it such a big deal to use compount litterall where you wrote "initializer list, NOT a compound literal". A compound is simply a cast afaik.

Comment: @traducerad, 1) "they" = *assignment statements* and initializers. 2) The code I presented works for me with `gcc -std=c11`. Your pastebin is flawed because the address of an *automatic* variable is *not* a constant, unlike the address of a variable with static duration such as in the above. 3) That's the point: compound literals are *not* casts and do not comprise casts, and they are not allowed in initializers.  Again, an initializer is not an assignment.  They have similar *but not identical* syntax, and different rules.